# Show/Hide Div which is also fixed

Tags: javascript, php, css, show-hide

I have been back and forth, back and forth and I'm sure there is a simple answer but this is starting to frustrate me.

What I need is a div box that can toggle upon clicking a button.  This is for a chat script that will always stay in the bottom hand corner.  I want the button to always be visible, and then if you click the button, the chat script will open.  You can then hopefully minimize it by clicking the button again.  I have got so close by playing around multiple times, but I need 2 divs (as the first div will contain the button which is always visible, and the second div will appear upon click).

UPDATE: The current script above opens and shuts the div with no problem. I just can't both the divs to follow the page when scrolling, despite them being "position:fixed;"

```js
$(function() {
  $('.button1').on('click', function() {
    $('.initiallyHidden').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
#calendar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  float: right;
}


}
#initiallyHidden {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="calendar">
  <button class="button1">Quick Chat</button>
</div>

<div class="initiallyHidden" style="display: none;">
  <iframe src="'.$url.'" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="yes" allowtransparency="yes" frameborder="0">
</div>
```

The current script above opens and shuts the div with no problem. I just can't both the divs to follow the page when scrolling, despite them being `position:fixed;`.

Please help me.

Comment: UPDATE:   The current script above opens and shuts the div with no problem.  I just can't both the divs to follow the page when scrolling, despite them being "position:fixed;"

Comment: Please add updates to the question itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("#button1").on("click", ()=>{ 
 $("#initiallyHidden").toggle();
});
```

```css
#chatbox { 
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  float:right;
}
#initiallyHidden { 
  bottom:10;
  right:0;
  float:right;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color:white;
}
#content {
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chatbox">
<div id="initiallyHidden" style="display: none;">
    Chat box
</div>
<button id="button1">Quick Chat</button>
</div>
<div id="content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, this is exactly what I need right now.  I have just tried but the box now doesn't seem to open when I click on the button.  I have had to  re-arrange, as for some reason I am echo'ing PHP, and doesn't let me add a div after the iframe...  `<div id="chatbox"><button id="button1">Quick Chat</button><div id="initiallyHidden" style="display: none;"><iframe src="'.$url.'" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="yes" allowtransparency="yes" frameborder="0"></div></div>`

Comment: scratch that, I've done it.  Thank you so much for your help!  You solved 2 of my problems without knowing it

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selectors are for IDs but your HTML elements have classes rather than IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your CSS you have `#initiallyHidden` instead of `.initiallyHidden`.
Same for calendar: `#calendar` instead of `.calendar`.

You have also an extra `}` inside your CSS

Remove the `float:right` property to the CSS too

Comment: Thanks, I have now changed this.  Unfortunately, the position still isn't come across as fixed

Comment: You have also an extra } inside your CSS file

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).on("load", function() {
   $("#initiallyHidden").hide();
});
$( "#calendar" ).click(function() {
  if($("#initiallyHidden").is(":visible")){
     $("#initiallyHidden").hide();
  }
  else{
    $("#initiallyHidden").show();
  }
});
```

```css
#calendar { position:fixed;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  float: right;
}
}
#initiallyHidden { 
position:fixed;
 bottom:0;
 right:0;
float:right;
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id = "calendar" type="button">Show calender!</button> 
<div id = "initiallyHidden">
Calendr
</div>
```